# Calculating averages for every n rows with missing data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column with 30-min averages, and I'd link to make a new column with 24-hour averages. I found this formula very useful:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(D:D,1+48*(ROW()-ROW($E$1))):INDEX(D:D,48*(ROW()-ROW($E$1)+1)))
```

However, about 15% of the rows have a `*` indicating data missing. In these instances, I would obviously like Excel not to divide by 48 to calculate the average, but divide by (48 - missing data). So, for example, if 5 cells have missing data within a 48 cell span, the average should be the sum of cell values divided by 43. But currently it is the sum divided by 48.

So how do I account for missing data in the above formula?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Average is supposed to deal with missing values automatically. If you just make them blank versus having a * it will do what you expect. That is the simplest approach by far.

Comment: Your formula already accounts for your missing values because `AVERAGE()` ignores non-numeric values. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGE-function-047bac88-d466-426c-a32b-8f33eb960cf6

Comment: Yes, I did an extra calculation and realised that you are right Kyle. Well, all this drama for nothing. Thank you very much for your replies!

Comment: @Ulla Since you figured it out, you should post that as an answer and accept it OR vote to close your own question.